# DateRange from @appbaseio/reactivesearch does not allow me to select past dates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, date-range, reactivesearch

I am using DateRange from @appbaseio/reactivesearch which does not allow me to select past dates, I need the date range to allow selecting past dates:

```
  import { ReactiveBase, DateRange } from "@appbaseio/reactivesearch";
         const [selectedDateRange, setSelectedDateRange] = useState({
           start: new Date(),
           end: new Date(),
           });
            <DateRange
                componentId="DateSensor"
                compoundClause="filter"
                dataField="mtime"
                value={selectedDateRange}
                onChange={handleDateChange}
                // title="DateRange"
                // defaultValue={{
                //   start: new Date("2017-04-01"),
                //   end: new Date("2017-04-07"),
                // }}
                placeholder={{
                  start: "Start Date",
                  end: "End Date",
                }}
                focused={true}
                numberOfMonths={1}
                autoFocusEnd={true}
                showClear={true}
                // queryFormat="date"
                // showFilter={true}
                // filterLabel="Date"
                style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
              />
```